# Modal opens up scrolled down to the nearest button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, microsoft-teams, fluent-ui

I am developing app for **Microsoft Teams using React and FluentUI**.
Problem is modal opens up scrolled down to the buttons. I fixed it by creating "X" close button in the top, however it is a walk-around. Styling of position does not seem to be a problem. Do you know what causes this kind of behavior?
[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8dkZ.png)

Comment: maybe it auto-focuses the first focusable element?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.